# Software Updater says 20.04.1 is available but won't upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, software-center, update-manager

Last time I used Software Updater it updated packages and after finishing, displayed "However, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is now available (you have 18.04)."

I clicked the [Upgrade ...] button but nothing happened. In the Terminal, typing

`$ sudo do-release-upgrade`

returned this message:

`Checking for a new Ubuntu release`
`Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`

Both Ubuntu Software and Synaptic report that there are no updates/upgrades for Ubuntu 18.04.5.

What do I do now?

Comment: What happens in the terminal if you `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt dist-upgrade`? Are additional packages installed?

Comment: Have you ppa included?

Answer (score 2):

Some packages might be half-configured, or broken.
Try the following commands as superuser:

1. Verify all packages have been fully configured:

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```
2. Update list of available package updates:

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
3. Do one of the following:

   - Upgrade outdated packages

     ```
     apt-get upgrade
     ```
   - Upgrade outdated packages and prerequisites, prioritizing important packages:

     ```
     apt-get dist-upgrade
     ```
4. Repeat Step 1 if necessary
5. Start release upgrade:

   ```
   do-release-upgrade
   ```

Please follow prompts and respond with caution; because release upgrade cannot be interrupted, nor "undone".

Comment: Many, many thanks to user3076105! This is exactly what I needed. Synaptic identified that a beta app had a new release but could not install the new release. So I removed the beta app and followed user3076105's instructions.  I modified the original solution to make it easier for beginners to follow, and to reflect what I actually did.